# Proving Collorary to Baire Category Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $(X, d)$ be a complete metric space. If $X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n, . . .$ is a sequence of subsets of $X$ such that $X = \bigcup^\infty_{n=1} X_n$, then for at least one $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$, the set $X_n$ has non-empty interior.

What I have done so far is: Suppose for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the sets $X_n$ are nowhere dense sets. Then, $X\backslash\bar{X_n}$ Will be open dense sets. By Baire Category Theorem, we know that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty X\backslash\bar{X_n}$ is dense too.

And I am stucked... Can you pease tell me what the next step would be ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $X_n$ non-empty interior being negated does **not** mean being nowhere dense. This is only true for $X_n$ closed.

The statement is true for $X_n$ closed (!). If they're not assumed to be closed, take the reals with all singletons rationals and the irrationals (as one non-closed set) as a counterexample.

If they're closed, so $\overline{X_n} = X_n$, then your proof concludes with:

Take $x \in \cap_n X \setminus \overline{X_n}$, as a dense set is surely non-empty. Then $x$ is in $X$ but in none of the $X_n$.

Comment: If $\bar X_n$ is not nowhere dense set, how do we know that $X\backslash X_n$ is open dense set? It seems you used Baire category theorem too..

Comment: I'm assuming the $X_n$ are closed and have non-empty interior in the last part.